# How to Match Using sed a Multi-Line Range Defined by More Than Two Bounds?

Tags: regex, bash, sed, pattern-matching, multiline

How do I...

...USE `sed` to match not just the standard 2-bound range, but a range characterized by a "multi-range" -- multiple (`>2`) submatches in some specific order...

...WHILE containing paired internal matches (e.g. `(` / `)`) that might overlap a pair of the multi-range's bounding patterns?

---

#### The Working Simple Range Match

Say I have a pattern whose content resembles something like this in a given formatting:

```
           someVar: SomeObj.someFunct
                        ("name1", "name2",
                         SomeConst)
```

In most cases like above, regardless of formatting for some constant `SomeObj.someFunct`, I could capture w/ the range pattern:

`cat $file | sed -ne '/^[ \t]*[a-zA-Z0-9_\: ]*SomeObj.someFunct/,/)/ {p}'`

where the dual range bounds are:

`/^[ \t]*[a-zA-Z0-9_\: ]*SomeObj.someFunct/`

and

`/)/`

So basically it's looking for the opening bit, then the closing parantheses.

---

#### Fail Cases

But this will occasionally fail  if there's stuff in between w/ `)`.  A simple example might be:

```
           someVar: SomeObj.someFunct
                        (thisTimeImCallingTheFunction(), "name2",
                         SomeConst)
```

It also fails if SomeObj.someFunct is on the next line, i.e.:

```
           someVar:
              SomeObj.someFunct("name1", "name2",
                         SomeConst)
```

---

#### A Multiply Bounded Range?

My idea is that I would like a "multi-range", or the equivalent of:

`/^[ \t]*[a-zA-Z0-9_\: ]*/`

and

`/SomeObj.someFunct/`

and

`/(/`

| and (optional)
|
| some arbitrary # of intermediary `(` and `)`)

and

`/)/`

...so the range would have to check through at least the 4 bounds, with the final two checking for an optional intermediate to guard against interior `(` / `)` pairs.

---

#### What I got

Unfortunately the naive version of this w/ out even considering the optional interior matches....

`cat $file | sed -ne '/^[ \t]*[a-zA-Z0-9_\: ]*/,/SomeObj.someFunct/,/(/,/)/ {p}'`

does not work.

It appears that the pattern `/check1/,/check2/,/check3/,/check4/` is not valid and some more complex strategy must be employed.

---

#### Summary of the Question

1. check a contiguous range defined by two end patterns and interior patterns in some specific order (but not necessarily on the same line)
2. for each additional `(` encountered, skip one `)` before the final match of the range `)`.

---

#### Note/Disclaimer

I searched for previous questions like this, figuring it was asked, but only found questions [asking about multiple ranges with standard dual bounds](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/248600/sed-multiple-ranges-between-patterns-with-one-pass), not a "multi range" in the sense of a single contiguous range defined by more than two bounding matches.

---

#### BONUS QUESTION:

Once I have such a multi-bound match, how can I multi-capture the following patterns:

1. the whitespace before `someVar`.
2. The three argument (including interiror `(` / `)` in the complex case.

Comment: My recollection is that you can do `/r1/,/r2/{/r3/,/r4/{s/x/y/;};}` sort of things, but a. I could be wrong, b. why waste you time? Life is short ;-) Look at EdMorton's answer for similar Qs and use `awk` with flag vars to indicate state (inside match1, inside match2, etc). Good luck.

Comment: Thanks, I'll give that a try.  I'm using this to edit a large number of files inline (application is automated codebase formatting cleanup) & line endings are unfortunately inconsistent, so `sed` provides such a trivial / fast solution for the line ending / inline editing annoyances in a Github-friendly way.  I'm basically looking to stick w/ `sed` for now, pushing the envelope to maximize the tool-based cleanup then later determining whether it's worth investing the time in a state-based parser script for the fringe cases (brute force cleanup is an obvious alternative, might take less time).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

sed is for s/old/new, that is all. If you're doing anything else with it then you're using constructs that became obsolete in the 1980s when awk was invented. With GNU awk for multi-char RS and the 3rd arg to match():

```
$ cat tst.awk
BEGIN { RS="^$" }
match($0,/([[:blank:]]*\w*:\s*SomeObj\.someFunct\s*\()(.*)/,a) {
    str = a[1]
    while ( match(a[2],/([^\)]*\))(.*)/,a) ) {
        str = str a[1]
        if ( !index(a[1],"(") ) {
            break
        }
    }
    print str
}

$ awk -f tst.awk file
           someVar: SomeObj.someFunct
                        (thisTimeImCallingTheFunction(), "name2",
                         SomeConst)
```

The above finds a string matching your starting regexp then keeps appending strings ending in `)` to that string until it reaches a string ending in `)` that doesn't contain a `(`.

Comment: As potong pointed out, `sed` can't fully solve the arbitrary parentheses matching.  Hence, I feel your answer most correctly matches my criteria -- showing a way to capture more complex patterns with an attractively short snippet that might even be turned into a one-liner, were one to get carried away.  That said, I appreciate all the answers.  Each offered some unique guidance & insight.  While eventually I may go the parser route, for now I will likely use `awk` to pick off a few more cleanups that `sed` can't, w/out having to muck w/ the time investment of a full-blown parser.

Answer (score 1):

Your first fail case with the nested function call cannot be handled in proper "regular" expressions. Some extensions like Perl's REs can deal with finding matching pairs of arbitrary nested things, but really you want an actual parser at this point.

Comment: Granted `sed`'s multi-line syntax is... awkward... in my experience, but I would find that somewhat surprising given that I've seen pretty complex / convoluted expressions w/ `sed`'s [regex engine](https://docstore.mik.ua/orelly/unix/sedawk/appa_03.htm).  Are you sure there's no way to handle/skip PREDICTABLE arbitrary matched pairs for modern versions of sed (source?)??  Also, I'm interested in the multi-range objective even if the skipping wasn't feasible.  And since you bring up switching to "an actual parser" what would you suggest? A custom python code or something?  Any references there?

Comment: Your results are going to vary with the version of sed in use. I regularly have to switch between gsed and non-Gnu sed, so I don't delve into what convoluted stuff Gnu makes possible. As for "actual parser" that's whatever you feel comfortable with. I'd probably write a state machine in Perl, but that's me.

Answer (score 1):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed -rn '/^\s*\w+:/!b;:a;N;/\)\s*$/!ba;/^\s*\w+:\s*SomeObj\.someFunct\s*\(/p;//d;D' file
```

This matches on the first variable and then appends further lines until a `)` followed by possible white space and the end of a line. The pattern space is then checked to see that all other matches are met and prints the pattern space if so. Othewise the first line is deleted and the process is repeated.

N.B. As stated regexp cannot be used for matching parens in all cases, this should be left to a parser.